# Burning disks fails with error 0x80020022 on MacbookPro 2012

Tags: macbook-pro, optical-drive, warranty

My Macbook Pro is about 22 weeks old and I keep getting this error:
0x80020022 (communication with drive failed) when trying to burn DVDs or "attempt to burn a disc failed"/unknown error -3 in iTunes.

I read the usual ["venting-anger-and-sharing-solutions"-thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2300720?start=0&tstart=0), but I'm expecting that, just like the last time my SuperDrive failed, it's just a bunch of voodoo solutions, ie.:
Nothing works for everybody, everybody tries everything and if it happens to work right after, they believe in it until it fails again.

I've burned less than 10 discs with my drive and I don't feel like spending two whole days on failing to fix it again. Do you think this is a warranty case? Or is there any site where the knowledge shared in Apple discussions is meaningfully combined so that I don't have to wade through ideas like "Restart Finder 11 times, worked for me".

Comment: I'd give Apple a call and just ask them if it's within your warranty, sounds like a ambiguous issue with no solid solution that they should help with

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would take it back to your Apple Reseller and tell them your problem. You're still under warranty, so most likely, it won't be an issue.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Ask Different! This site is meant to be a collaborative reference of all things Apple, hence answers should be useful to the community at large. In this case, it would help to know why you think your and is correct, with pointers to your sources; if it is your **personal opinion** only,  a comment on the original question is the right place to post it, not an answer.

Comment: However, he doesn't have enough rep to post a comment yet...